Google spreadsheet / FIND vs Xlookup solution / find value in array
can anybody help ?
Example -
sheet / table one in the row will be name and surname, in the column header date dd/mm/yyyy/, for the name, if person is not present --> will be letter H (holiday).
in second list/tab, we track the task - responsible name/date / revised due date.
In case, we will select a date or revised due date (Two specific column), for responsible who is on vacation´(V) will be the cell with his name highlighted as red.
I tried this part, but not sure, how to extend the search within the whole array and how  to extend for the revised due date. Still in progress. Any idea what function might fit to my expectation.
At the end, I want to add it as conditional formatting to the cell / RESPONSIBLE
enter image description here
Xlookup function - partially working
Find worked also partially

share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Please, Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.

I'm sorry, I have have read, and re-read the question but I don't understand the source data OR the outcome that you are trying to achieve. Would you please edit the question to include sample data, an example of the outcome, and an explanation of the scenario using the sample data and expected outcome.
